# Are questions about purely remote employment on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

The [on-topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page does not explicitly include or exclude discussion of online 'workplaces'. Some people find, hire, interact, and fire all online. Are questions about interactions with people whom you do not interact with in person on topic for this site?

Comment: We've had questions about remote workers interacting with one another before. Ask away :)

Comment: Suggest you retitle this to "remote (only)" positions which is what I think these are more commonly referred to as.

Comment: @Lilienthal yeah, the current title sounds like it's about dating.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sure!  Remote employment is still employment, and "the workplace" doesn't only mean the building.  We've had several questions related to remote employees already.

Answer (score 1):

I think they're increasingly relevant and interesting. I have both local and remote workers and use different strategies with them, and have very different attitudes towards them. So they would elicit quite different answers (from me at any rate).